# Component Design - Visual Basic DotNetBar

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a form with way more than 1500 objects in multiple tabs, and is getting awful to maintain and develop new features.

I'm using DotNetBar Components so I wanted to design each tab (supertabcontrolpanel) separately and add them manually in run time.

But I can't seem to be able to design solely the component.

Comment: Of course it is, your post is too vague for an answer right now. Not sure this is the right path though.

Comment: @OneFineDay Updated. how would you handle it ?

Comment: Never used DotNetBar Components, but normally you'd approach this problem by developing **UserControl**s.

Comment: @Mikail, it is hard to say exactly(as I can't see your form nor do we know your requirements), but `UserControls` are definitely helpful here if repetitive creation of like groups of controls is necessary.